# Magento 2.3.2. CE How to uninstall a module?

Tags: upgrade, uninstall-module

Overview:

I have an M2EPro module which I need to update but the current iteration seems to be in the wrong folder and may be causing issues with another module.

I originally thought that I had manually installed the module so I disabled it, ran `setup:upgrade` and then removed the folders via FTP. I then got the following error(s):

```
Warning: require(/home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/../m2epro/magento2-extension/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 80

Warning: require(/home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/../m2epro/magento2-extension/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 8`0

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/../m2epro/magento2-extension/registration.php' (include_path='/home/*****/*****/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/*****/*****/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 80
```

This would suggest the current module was updated via composer so I would need to uninstall it via composer. So I put everything back as it was, and then tried this:

```
bin/magento module:uninstall m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2
```

This is the vendor/module name in the composer.json file in the module root. Result: Unknown module(s).

So I tried the same again with the module name that appears in `module:status` - Ess_M2ePro

```
bin/magento module:uninstall Ess_M2ePro
```

Result: `Ess_M2ePro is not an installed composer package`

So I've got a manual uninstall telling me that it's a composer package, and composer telling me it's not.

Does anyone know how I can uninstall this, please?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composer package name is declared in `composer.json` in Magento root folder. The composer packe for m2epro extension is `m2epro/magento2-extension`.

As you mentioned you reverted m2e extension back to the vendor folder, so you can run: `bin/magento module:uninstall Ess_M2ePro` to remove the module, that command also removes the composer package of the module.

If you can't revert back m2e extension to vendor folder, then you should use `composer require m2epro/magento2-extension`, then run uninstall command: `bin/magento module:uninstall Ess_M2ePro`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That makes sense. I have "m2epro/magento2-extension" under "require" in my composer.json. But, alas, no beans. I'm getting an 'unknown module' error for "bin/magento module:uninstall m2epro/magento2-extension"

Comment: I've updated the answer, please give it a try. If the issue still persists, please let me know. I'll help.

Comment: have you try `composer remove m2epro/magento2-extension`